# How can I determine if a Zap is turned off when I call a Zap with a Webhook?

Tags: zapier

I have a working Zapier Webhook call from a .Net Web Application.   However, I always receive "success" even when the Zap is turned off.  Which I suppose makes sense--the "success" pertains to the webhook itself, not the Zap.
[image]

In my .Net Web Application, I want to raise an exception if the zap is turned off.  How can I determine if a Zap is turned off?

I figure this answer is probably in some Zapier documentation, but I can't see to get a hit (I am sorta new to Zapier).

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

> the "success" pertains to the webhook itself, not the Zap.

You've got it correct here. Hook ingestion happens separately from running zaps. The basic flow is this:

1. Hook arrives
2. We record it and put it into the processing queue
3. We respond "succcess" if that happened without error (which it basically always should, we don't want to miss hooks!)
4. One that hook reaches the front of our queue, we find the relevant zap and run it with the hook as input.

Since step 3 happens before step 4, we unfortunately can't return any info about the hook as part of that initial response. It's designed this way so that we can process tons of hooks very quickly. If we had to wait for the Zap query, it would slow down that process a lot.

The good news is, you can send all the hooks you like and we'll ignore the ones that aren't relevant.

Sorry I don't have a better answer!

Comment: That's not good news in any sense!

Say I am a bank, and you are sending money into an account you once held here; if I don't check that the account is still active at some point around accepting your cash, wouldn't you have the right to be upset?

> "we unfortunately can't return any info about the hook as part of that initial response."

It seems you don't ever tell them.

Comment: As the customer, now say you hold multiple accounts, one of which was dead - I think you'd consider it only polite that I inform you that you misdirected your cash. 

Dear Mr. Customer, here's the cash (or webhook POST) you are missing.

And no, you can accept the cash as people throw it at you. Just be good enough to inform them afterwards!