# Does anything notice if a Webhook owned by Zapier is not served by an active zap?

Tags: error-handling, event-listener, zapier

I have some systems firing POSTs at Zapier webhooks. Occasionally the Zap that handles the POST is switched off. This is a situation I need to be aware of.

For the webhooks and raw webhook endpoints (made for my Webhook by Zapier Zaps), how can I determine which are failing to listen for incoming HTTP requests?

I've had a remote system assume that Zapier is going to receive the messages, instead they evaporate into nothingness.

Comment: Gah. Seems Zapier just runs off with your data, doesn't reject. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174791/how-can-i-determine-if-a-zap-is-turned-off-when-i-call-a-zap-with-a-webhook

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally the Zap that handles the POST is switched off. This is a situation I need to be aware of.

There's a [Zapier Manager](https://zapier.com/help/create/other-functions/manage-your-account-and-zaps-with-zapier-manager#add-zapier-manager-as-a-trigger) app that does this! You can set the trigger to be "when zap X is turned off, which would notify you accordingly".

Re: Not knowing if your data is being received. That's interesting feedback and has been logged internally accordingly.